# Open file manager in Dreamhost

Tags: dreamhost

How to open file manager in Dreamhost? I want to take backup and edit some files in my website. I try to find file manager in Dreamhost server, But I can't find it. Please, provide information about How to open file manager in Dreamhost server.

Comment: This is slightly unclear. Please expand your question and add more details.

Comment: I want to take backup of my website. So, I need to open file manager in Dreamhost server.

Comment: Please explain the exact problem.

Comment: I can't find file manager in Dreamhost server. I want to path or location for open file manager in Dreamhost server.

Comment: Dreamhost uses a proprietary control panel (rather than the standard CPanel), so many tools, such as File Manager, are missing. You have to use their suite of tools.  As other posters have pointed out, they have a web based "webftp" tool, but can also SFTP directly to your site and pull your files that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find instructions on [DreamHost Knowledge Base](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/sections/203242517-Connecting-To-Your-Server).

The short version is use https://webftp.dreamhost.com/ but I would suggest you to learn how to use an SFTP client on your desktop. Instructions are on the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Click the "WebFTP" button under any fully hosted domain on the Manage Domains section of the DreamHost Panel.